Hilbert polynomial of quadratic 3-fold
Consider the  subset of projective $4$-space given by $5$-tuples $[v:w:x:y:z]$ with $v^2 + w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 0$.
This is birational to projective $3$-space. How can I compute its Hilbert polynomial? I known that it should be a degree 3 polynomial whose leading coefficient should be $\frac{1}{3}$ due to its degree, but what about the other terms?

$(t+1)(t + 2)(2t + 3)/6$.

Let $S=k[v,\ldots,z]$ and $f=v^2 + w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 0$. We write $P_{M}(t)$ to denote the Hilbert polynomial of $M$. Since vector space dimension is additive on short exact sequences, the following short exact sequence
$$
0\to S(-2)\xrightarrow{f} S\to S/fS\to 0$$
gives $P_{S/fS}(t)=P_{S}(t)-P_{S}(t-2)$ for $t$ large enough. The Hilbert polynomial of $S$ is $\displaystyle\binom{4+t}{4}$, so $$P_{S/fS}(t)=\frac{1}{6}(t+1)(t+2)(2t+3).$$
A slightly different approach is to use the Hilbert series $H_M(t)=\sum_k (\dim M_k) t^k$. In this approach, we use the fact that $H_S(t)=\dfrac{1}{(1-t)^5}$, and the above exact sequence yields $H_{S/fS}(t)=(1-t^2)H_S(t)=\dfrac{(1+t)}{(1-t)^4}$. Expanding out and combining like terms will give the same answer as above.
